# Form validation using $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation

This is my code for form validation.Here `alert("validation done")` should be displayed after validation of every inputs.But its returning for each and every input.Whats the issue here?

```js
var app=angular.module('myApp',[])
app.controller('myController',function($scope){
$scope.clickMe = function(){
debugger
   $form = $('#myForm');
        $form.find('div input.required').each(function () {debugger
            var $this = $(this)
            if ($this.val().trim() == '') {
                $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        })
        
        alert("validation done")
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<form id="myForm" >
<div>
  <input type="text" class="required">
  <input type="date" class="required">
  <select class="required">
  <option>AAA</option>
  <option>BBB</option>
  </select>
</div>
</form>
<button ng-click="clickMe()">submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any error in browser's console?

Comment: @gurvinder372 No.

Comment: The code is not running at all. There is a typo `$('#myFrom')` should be `$('#myForm')`

Comment: @DrColossos yea thanks.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: I must say that you're doing it totally wrong way. Try not to use JQuery when developing with AngularJS. Check this article it's really good: 

https://gabrieleromanato.name/introduction-to-angularjs-for-jquery-developers

To do form validation you should go and check ng-required directive, and angularjs validations: 

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp

Comment: @pegla ok sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here alert("validation done") should be displayed after validation of
>   every inputs.

In that case

- this `alert` should be inside the `each` loop
- `$('#myFrom');` should changed to `$('#myForm');`
- remove `return false` within `if`

**Demo**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.clickMe = function() {
    $form = $('#myForm');
    var isValid = true;
    $form.find('div input.required').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this)
      if ($this.val().trim() == '') {
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
        isValid = false;
      }
      if (isValid) {
        alert("validation done"); //notice the change in placement of this alert
      }
      return true;
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <form id="myForm">
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="required">
      <input type="date" class="required">
      <select class="required">
  <option>AAA</option>
  <option>BBB</option>
  </select>
    </div>
  </form>
  <button ng-click="clickMe()">submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: when I hit `submit` without entering any values..border should be added for every input right?but here its checking only for first input.

Comment: I want to show `alert(validation done)` after entering all 3 values.

Comment: Can I write validation for selecr too in that same if condition?

Comment: Yes, you will need to change the selector to `$form.find('div input.required, div select.required')`

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo `$('#myFrom')` should be `$('#myForm')`.

You can also use the built-in angular.element() function, that work without jQuery (though in a more light-weight version) and are sufficent for your code.